# Memcached different type of cache

Tags: java, database, caching, memcached

Can anyone explain in plain English what is the difference between singleCache, multiCache, assignCache in memcached?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In memcached there's no difference. All data in memcached are stored as pairs key -> value.

The terms singleCache, multiCache, assignCache are from [Simple Spring Memcached](http://code.google.com/p/simple-spring-memcached/) project and mean:

- assignCache: is used to store / fetch single value under / from the same cache key independently on intercepted method's parameters
- singleCache: is used to stor  / fetch single value under / from single cache key created by concatenating namespace and intercepted method's parameters annotated with [ParameterValueKeyProvider](https://simple-spring-memcached.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/apidocs/com/google/code/ssm/api/ParameterValueKeyProvider.html)
- multiCache: is used store / fetch many values are  under / from many cache keys created by concatenating namespace and intercepted method's parameters annotated with [ParameterValueKeyProvider](https://simple-spring-memcached.googlecode.com/svn/docs/2.0.0/apidocs/com/google/code/ssm/api/ParameterValueKeyProvider.html), where exactly one of the annotated parameters is collection and result of the method is also a collection.